# Regex valid numbers with thousand separator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm doing a validation in asp.net textbox, and the textbox only allows user to input number

i.e.

valid numbers:

```
1234
12.345
12,345,678.231
12,345,678
```

invalid numbers:

```
-1234
12.23.45.67
12,
12,34,56
12,345,6
```

I'm trying to use a regex to validate the user's input on client side with the below regex:

```
^(?=.+)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

The problem is:

the above regex only consider below as valid:

```
1234
12.345
```

How to modify the above regex to check if the thousand separator being entered into the correct place or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this seems to work `^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mU2iZ7)

Comment: I would suggest [0-9] instead of /d since, in asp.net /d will match ALL unicode digits. e.g 1,४४1,234.234४ would match, since the odd looking characters are digits in another language